# Loop multiple vars with loop_var Ansible

Tags: ansible, uri

I would need to have a loop inside of URI module that runs simultaneous a task in one go. I have tried something like the example below, but it's not working since just the last value will be taken in consideration:

```
- uri:
      method: PATCH
      url: https://10.10.10.10/api/xyz
      status_code: 200, 201
      force_basic_auth: yes
      user: user
      password: pass
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs: no
      body_format: "json"
      body:
       replace:
         data:
              - enabled: "{{ x.enabled }}"
                if_name: "{{ x.name }}"
              - enabled: "{{ y.enabled }}"
                if_name: "{{ y.name }}"
  loop: "{{ vm.params | default([]) | flatten(levels=1) }}"
  loop_control:
       loop_var: x
       loop_var: y
```

Is any way to achieve this with loop, loop_control and loop_var or using it in conjunction with other modules that won't be deprecated in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```
site.yml -
---
- hosts: 
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: main.yml
      with_items: 
        - "{{  vm.params | default([]) | flatten(levels=1)  }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: x

main.yml -
---
- uri:
      method: PATCH
      url: https://10.10.10.10/api/xyz
      status_code: 200, 201
      force_basic_auth: yes
      user: user
      password: pass
      return_content: yes
      validate_certs: no
      body_format: "json"
      body:
       replace:
         data:
              - enabled: "{{ x.enabled }}"
                if_name: "{{ x.name }}"

I'm not using the 'y' variable in here as that is not possible based on the code you put on.
```

Answer (score 0):

`multi_loop_var.yml`

```
---
- include: echo.yml
  with_items:
    - a: "How are you"
      b: "I'm fine"
    - a: "Good bye"
      b: "See you again"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: x
```

`echo.yml`

```
---
- name: echo
  command: echo "Ask:{{ x.a }} - Answer:{{ x.b }}"
  register: output
- debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```